# What is the shortest progression?

Tags: sequences-and-series

An arithmetic progression (e.g. 1,4,7,10...) can be infinitely long. But how short can it be? Is the sequence 1, 4 still considered a progression?

Comment: Even $1$ by itself, of length 1.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on your definition. Some would say you need to have two terms in order to have a well-defined difference.  Some would say that $1$ is an arithmetic progression (of length $1$ and any difference you like).

Personally, I consider the empty sequence $\{\}$ an arithmetic progression as well, simply because "there is a number $d$ such that the difference between any two adjacent terms is equal to $d$" is *vacuously* true.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
with initial term 1,
difference 3,
and length 2.

Note that
*any* sequence
of length 2
is a linear progression,
and that
any sequence of length $n$
is a progression of order
$n-1$
(i.e.,
has its $n-1$ difference
constant).